# Облако для хранения файлов Android-приложения

Tags: android, облако

Заказчику нужно простое клиент серверное приложение без бэкэнда, но с возможностью динамического обновления контента. (да-да, звучит смешно, но это простой оффлайн магазин). Нужен сервис для хранения контента (картинка + текстовое описание). Грубо говоря, приложение при запуске идёт на облако и выкачивает картинки с описаниями (например разложенные отдельно по папкам "фото", "описание"), и отображать в ListView. Заказчик загрузит еще картинку с описанием - при обновлении ListView они появятся. Вопрос в том, знает ли кто, где такое можно реализовать (вроде как dropbox путем замены в пути к файлу "dropbox.com" на "dropboxusercontent.com"), но у меня не получилось, работает ли еще этот способ? И еще важный момент, Adapter'у у AdapterView нужно знать кол-во элементов, поэтому еще нужно чтобы была возможность получать от папки в облаке кол-во элементов в ней. Или хранить отдельный файлик с числом элементов? Кто может подсказать верный вариант, облачный сервис, или как бы он поступил в решении этой проблемы? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Среди сервисов [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) есть Realtime Database и Storage.

Comment: Тоже за Firebase. Мы используем в разных проектах, очень удобно. Загрузка файла на сервер выглядит вот так:
Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("path/test_image.jpg"));
UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.child("images" +file.getLastPathSegment()).putFile(file);

Подробнее тут https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files

Answer (score 1):

Уверяю вас, лучше Dropbox вы не найдете. Простая облачная файловая система с ясно описанным [Java API](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v2.1.x/).

[Повтыкайте примеры](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/tree/master/examples/android/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/android) для Android

Comment: Возможно, вы захотите удаленно управлять URL или именами файлов. Для этого может подойти Firebase Remote Config. https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/

Comment: @barmaley Большое спасибо за совет. Возможно ли реализовать все это без необходимости авторизации в dropbox при запуске приложения? Приложение может скачать кто угодно из Google Play, и оно должно брать файлы только с одного аккаунта в dropbox. В примерах я не нашел такого, там нужна авторизация в сервисе.

Comment: если Dropbox папка публичная, то можно скачивать вообще без авторизации и даже без Java API